# Files not showing in Trash

Tags: nautilus, trash

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the Nautilus file manager. Until recently, I've been able to move files to the Trash just fine. Now, when I choose to "Move file to Trash" from my file manager, the files don't showing up in my Trash, but they do show up in my `~/.local/share/Trash/files` folder. Even when I right click and view Trash's properties, it reports 0 files.

I recently had to forcefully empty my trash using rm `-rf ~/.local/share/Trash`. By doing this, did I accidentally bork up my trash folder? How can I fix this so that trashed files appear in my Trash again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working. After I set permissions so that the user could create and delete files in the rebuilt `~/.local/share/Trash` folder, tried logging out and logging back in. Now trashed files appear in my trash again.